# Prove that $\mathcal{P}(A)\cap\mathcal{P}(B)\subseteq\mathcal{P}(A\cap B)$ for all $A, B$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> **Problem.** Prove that $\mathcal{P}(A)\cap\mathcal{P}(B)\subseteq\mathcal{P}(A\cap B)$ for all $A, B$

This is what I have so far but not sure if it's right.

Let $X \in \mathcal{P}(A \cap B)$. Then each element of $X$ is an element of $A$ and $B$, hence $X$ is also in $\mathcal{P}(A)$ and $\mathcal{P}(B)$ $\Longrightarrow$ $X \in \mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B)$.

Now Let $Y \in \mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B)$. Then $Y \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ and $Y \in \mathcal{P}(B)$. Therefore each element of $Y$ is an element of $A$ and $B$. Hence each element of $Y$ is in $A \cap B$ $\Longrightarrow$ $Y \in \mathcal{P}(A \cap B)$. Hence we have shown that any set in $\mathcal{P}(A \cap B)$ is in $\mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B)$ and vice versa.

Comment: What is $P(A)$ ? the power set of $A$ ? what have you tried ?

Comment: What have you tried? How do you usualy solve problem like this? It will help us know what kind of proof you are looking for.

Comment: If you want to show that $X\subseteq Y$, then pick an arbitrary element of $X$ and show that it follows that it must also be an element of $Y$.  So... for your problem, pick an arbitrary element $x\in (\mathcal{P}(A)\cap\mathcal{P}(B))$ and use what you know about intersections and powersets to show that it follows that you must have $x\in \mathcal{P}(A\cap B)$

Comment: I added what I've tried.

Comment: If all you wanted to show was that $\mathcal{P}(A)\cap \mathcal{P}(B)\subseteq \mathcal{P}(A\cap B)$ then your entire first line in your attempt is unnecessary since that is used to show the reverse.  Otherwise, your attempt appears correct (*though could benefit greatly from line breaks to improve readability*)